# Slider doesn't work as expected (JQuery, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Below you can find my JQuery and JavaScript Code.

**What is it?** it is a slider witch starts automatically if the user don't hover any of the divboxes. If he hover a divbox the slider stops and the divbox expand. If the user mouseout the divbox colaps and the automatically slider starts again.

**What is the problem?** If I'm over a divbox the slider stops, so far so good. But if I now went with my mouse (fast) over the next divbox this new divbox expand and the old divbox where I was before collaps still everything is fine. But now the automatically slider starts again...**but it should stop!** here is a little picture

**What do I think the problem can be?** Is it possible that this is because I went to fast to the next divbox? If I do this slowly it works fine...

/*code error*/

Comment: That's quite a bit of code to look through... Could you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the issue? It would be much easier to understand and solve the problem if I had a working example.

Comment: mhm this works with pictures in the background witch switch ...kinda hard to create a jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is showing a /code error/ so I can't see your code that I'm assuming you provided.

My gut reaction is that when you mouseout of the divbox, you are probably triggering an animation on the divbox that has a callback function to start the slider. Maybe its possible that when youmove your mouse quickly onto a new divbox it stops the slider, but since the animation on the closing divbox is still parsing, the callback to start the slider fires after you already moved to a new div, causing the slider to continue.

Just a guess.

Comment: Following on from this, you could set a flag when you tell the slider to stop, and when your callback fires (to start the slider) check this flag first. You'd obviously need to reset the flag when you do want to start it again.